# How to access getState in redux toolkit in typescript?

Tags: typescript, redux-toolkit

I have an `createAsyncThunk` operation and want to access `getState` inside the toolkit. I am not sure about how to cast `getState` type in typescript:

```
export const getInitialDatapoints = createAsyncThunk(
  'userSlice/getInitDatapoints',
  async (args, { getState as AppState }) => {
    const geoData = await getLocationData();
    const googleData = getState().userSlice;
    const response = await updateUserData(1);
    return response.data;
  }
);
```

where `AppStore` is:

```
export type AppState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;
```

I get this error:

```
Property 'AppState' does not exist on type 'GetThunkAPI<{}>'
```

Can anyone help in solving this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't assert types while destructuring objects. Also, you need to call `getState` before it can be asserted as `AppState`.

You can do this instead:

```
const getInitialDatapoints = createAsyncThunk(
        "userSlice/getInitDatapoints",
        async (args, api) => {
            const appState = api.getState() as AppState
            const geoData = await getLocationData();
            const googleData = appState.userSlice;
            const response = await updateUserData(1);
            return response.data;
        }
    );
```